# Angularjs display length of items where property equals

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this html markup:

```
<table class="table tenant-table text-center">
  <tr>
    <th class="text-center">Property Number</th>
    <th class="text-center">Location</th>
    <th class="text-center">Cost / Value</th>
    <th class="text-center">Commercial Tenants</th>
    <th class="text-center">Multy-family Tenants</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td>{{property.PropertyType}}</td>
    <td>{{property.City}}</td>
    <td>&euro;{{property.CurrentValue}}</td>
    <td>{{property.Tenants.length}}</td> // where tenanttype = 1
    <td>{{property.Tenants.length}}</td> // where tenanttype = 2
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to know if I can directly access the length of the tenants in the property where tenanttype equals 1 or 2.

I know there are ways in the controller I can calculate this but I want to know if its possible to do this directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td ng-if='property.Tenants' ng-repeat="item in property.Tenants | filter : {tenanttype:1}" ng-if="$last">{{$index + 1}}</td>// where tenanttype = 1
    <td ng-if='property.Tenants' ng-repeat="item in property.Tenants | filter : {tenanttype:2}" ng-if="$last">{{$index + 1}}</td>// where tenanttype = 2
    <td colspan="2" ng-if='!property.Tenants'>0</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Laziale instead of double ng-repeats - you can use expression like this: `{{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:1}).length }}`. Just look to my answer.

Comment: It's overkill to be honest, you are repeating all the filtered items , and then only showing the amount according the list index. Better to not use a repeat, and just get the size of the filtered array. As shown in my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to set default value as 0 until the value is not null?

Comment: See my updated answer for adding a default `0` value if `property.Tenants` is not present

Comment: @Laziale, yes, it is possible, look at the updated answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you duplicated `<td ng-if='!property.Tenants'>0</td>`. But the answer above is really not a good approach - to much overhead...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this? Where you only want to show `{{property.Tenants.length}}` when the `tenanttype` equals 1 or 2?

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td>{{property.PropertyType}}</td>
    <td>{{property.City}}</td>
    <td>&euro;{{property.CurrentValue}}</td>
    <td>{{property.Tenants.length}}</td>
    <td ng-if="property.tenanttype === 1 || property.tenanttype === 2">{{property.Tenants.length}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Update**

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td>{{property.PropertyType}}</td>
    <td>{{property.City}}</td>
    <td>&euro;{{property.CurrentValue}}</td>
    <td>{{property.Tenants.length}}</td> // where tenanttype = 1
    <td ng-if="property.tenanttype === 1">
        {{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:1}).length}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="property.tenanttype === 2">
        {{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:2}).length}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

**UPDATE : show 0 when value is not present**

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td>{{property.PropertyType}}</td>
    <td>{{property.City}}</td>
    <td>&euro;{{property.CurrentValue}}</td>
    <td>{{property.Tenants.length}}</td> // where tenanttype = 1
    <td ng-if="property.tenanttype === 1">
        {{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:1}).length}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="property.tenanttype === 2">
        {{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:2}).length}}
    </td>
    <td ng-if="!property.Tenants">0</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, yes, but I just need the length of the tenants. For example, one property can have both tenants with tenant type of 1 and tenant type of 2. I want to get them both and display them in separate column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or just in one expression:

```
<td>{{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:1}).length }}</td>
<td>{{(property.Tenants | filter:{tenanttype:2}).length }}</td>
```

Comment: tenanttype is part of property.tenants

Comment: I need to get all tenants in that property where the tenant type equals 1 and then all tenants in the same property where tenant type equals 2 in another column

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in purchasePropertyData.properties">
    <td>{{property.PropertyType}}</td>
    <td>{{property.City}}</td>
    <td>&euro;{{property.CurrentValue}}</td>
    <td><span ng-if="property.Tenants.indexOf(1) > -1" ng-bind="property.Tenants.length"></span></td>
    <td><span ng-if="property.Tenants.indexOf(2) > -1" ng-bind="property.Tenants.length"></span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: please note that the property can have tenants with both tenant types of 1 and 2. From your code I think you're showing only if tenant type is equal to 1 or 2

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what is tenanttype? An array of numbers?

Comment: Its property in tenants array